# How to delete a document that has a subdocument in firestore database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How to delete a document that has a subdocument in firestore database?

Here is the collection structure

[image]
[image]
I would like to delete the document `doc("3F0SezA3")`

I tried these below but none had work, i am getting `console.log('deleted')` but in the database the document is still showing

```
firebase.firestore()
    .collection("users")
    .doc("3F0SezA3").delete()
    .then(function () {
                console.log('deleted');
              }, function (error) {
                console.error('Delete Error', error);
              });
```

```
 firebase.firestore()
.collection("users").doc("3F0SezA3")
.collection("movives").doc("asdrftgyqweAsdghj120a").delete()
.then(function () {
                console.log('deleted');
              }, function (error) {
                console.error('Delete Error', error);
              });
```

Comment: What are are you seeing that suggests the document is not deleted?  Did you check for errors on each delete?  Please edit the question to explain in more detail.

Comment: no error is being thrown noting is happening @DougStevenson

Comment: Your code doesn't show any error handling being done with the promises returned by delete().

Comment: Could you include the structure of your db?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "How to delete a document that has a subdocument in firestore database?" You want to select the subdocument and delete the parent? OR, you want to delete the parent and THEN delete the subdocument?

Comment: Also, you write: "I tried these below but none had work, i am getting console.log('deleted') but in the database the document is still showing". Which document is still showing? And to which code corresponds the "deleted" log?

Comment: i would like to delete the sub and parent document and the ```console.log('deleted');```is showing for the two snippet  of code i tried @RenaudTarnec

Comment: You want to delete them at the same time? Do you have both the document ids? Also, is there any specific security rules in your Firestore DB?

Comment: yes i would like to delete them at the same time and i have the document ids also there is no specific security rules in your Firestore DB just read and write set to true @RenaudTarnec

Comment: Are you deleting all of the documents inside the movies subcollection? Because according to the documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#delete_documents) even if the parent document is deleted, the subcollections are not automatically deleted. But I think firestore removes the collection if there are no documents in it. So make sure you're deleting all the documents inside the subcollection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to delete the two documents at the same time, the best is to use a [batched write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes), as follows:

```
var batch = firebase.firestore().batch();

var parentRef = firebase.firestore()
    .collection("users")
    .doc("3F0SezA3");
batch.delete(parentRef);

var childRef = parentRef
    .collection("movives")
    .doc("asdrftgyqweAsdghj120a");
batch.delete(childRef);

batch.commit()
.then(function () {
    console.log("Docs deleted")
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error)
});
```

Comment: hi @RenaudTarnec how can i delete this part ```firebase.firestore().collection("matches").doc("3F0SezA3");```    alone, i tried this ```firebase.firestore().collection("matches").doc("3F0SezA3").delete()
            .then(function () {
                console.log("Docs deleted")
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }); ```  but it is not working

Comment: Hi, what you tried should normally work. Do you get any error.

Comment: ok what i am trying to get at is how to delete a document with aboout over 100 sub document, the sub documents all have dynamic ids @RenaudTarnec

Comment: Since queries in Firestore are shallow, you need to query all the sub-documents in the sub-collection of this Document and delete them. See also this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/delete-collections

Comment: thanks, could you please show me what path i would have to use ```function deleteAtPath(path) {}``` to  initiate the server-side delete @RenaudTarnec

Comment: It should be `users/3F0SezA3/movives` if I correctly understand your case.

Comment: Hello, yes I’m a freelancer and I would be happy to collaborate with you. You can contact me through my website www.rtaconsulting.eu, there is a contact form.